# Is it possible to get the Windows logon name with site running asp.net forms authentication?

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication, forms, mixed

I have a website with a large user base configured with asp.net 2.0 forms authentication.  Before the user logs in via forms authentication is it possible to retrieve the windows login name/user account name on the machine they are using?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

It certainly is possible--by adding another web application to your system. Here's roughly how I have done it:

Your primary web app uses Forms authentication. On the forms login page, any user that is determined to be on the local LAN (check IP address), redirect them to another app that uses Windows authentication. In this second app, you can determine the user (assuming the browser is configured to send credentials automatically to the zone in which your app resides), then set a cookie which your first app can read, and redirect the user back to the original app.

This does work.

Comment: How do you set the cross-app cookie?

Comment: @awe use the same `machineKey` as in SingleSignOn: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312020/single-sign-on-in-asp-net-cookie-name-machinekey-and-what-more

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no - if the user has not logged on, they are browsing anonymously, and are therefore unknown to the server. There is no way to identify them.

Once they're logged on, if you're using impersonation use `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`. However, for forms authentication there's no direct way to ask the browser for their Windows credentials as they may not even be running Windows!

Comment: Many thanks. Actually it does not matter if it is before or after login, I just need to know the client os username. After forms login WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name returns nt authority/network service. So I assume this is not possible without some kind of activeX control. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Indeed, I (incorrectly) assumed you were using impersonation - I've updated my answer.

Comment: Shigg: Actually, it is possible, if your site is in the trusted zone and using windows auth.

Answer (score 1):

This would only be possible if you were using Windows Authentication in your web application and then only if the user had logged in.
The kind of information you are after is not sent as part of the web request (quite rightly) and is therefore unknown to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Not BEFORE no (not from the server).

Depending on the type of Auth you use, though, and the way the site is configured, you CAN get them to log in with their windows details.

Answer (score 0):

See [**Mixing Forms and Windows Security in ASP.NET** on Microsoft's MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx).

The main difference with @TheObjectGuy answer is that instead of using 2 websites, this does all in a single website by configuring IIS to use the Integrated Windows authentication just in a "single" page (WinLogin.aspx).