# redirection between asp .net interfaces using cookies without querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have two asp .net interfaces:

```
  1. app1.domain.com
  2. app2.domain.com
```

In default page of both, there is a link button  from which we can switch between them. Previously we use query strings to pass username and password. But now we want to use cookies.
So in click event of link button, I have code like this:

```
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("MYCookie", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    cookie.Domain = "domain.com";
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
    cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    cookie.Secure = true;

    cookie.Values.Add("Username", Username.ToString());
    cookie.Values.Add("UserId", UserId.ToString());
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    Response.Redirect(destinationAddress);
```

Now, in default page of other application am reading cookie as:

```
    protected override void InitializeCulture() {
     if (Request.Cookies["MYCookie"] != null) {
       HttpCookie cookie = null;
      cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("MYCookie");
         }
      }
```

but here am finding Request.Cookies["MYCookie"] as null. Am i missing anything? Please advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing ASP.NET cookies across sub-domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589630/sharing-asp-net-cookies-across-sub-domains)

Comment: you can use http meta tag refresh. Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the problem is your domain.

Change `cookie.Domain = "domain";` to be `cookie.Domain = ".domain.com";`

Comment: I have customized it in web.config file as domain.com... But it didnot help

Comment: You need the leading dot `.` Do you have that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add HttpCookie same Path property for both app1 and app2

Comment: Do you mean like this? cookie.Path = "/default.aspx";

Comment: @Sanjay the last thing i can think of is Machine key. You can read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312020/single-sign-on-in-asp-net-cookie-name-machinekey-and-what-more

Answer (score 0):

Response.Redirect generates **ThreadAbortException**. 
All the changes made in your cookie will be lost. so you can use,

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="10; URL=your url" />
```

c# code:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlMeta meta = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlMeta();
meta.HttpEquiv = "Refresh";
meta.Content = "10; URL=your url";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
```

And set you cookie as like

```
cookie.Domain = ".domain.com";
```